# How to change storage path in laravel 5.3 to public?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In `laravel 5.3`, if I upload a file from a form, it will be stored in own storage directory. Then I should create a `symlink` to that storage path in public path.

I can't use creating symlinks on my system because of the limitation. How can I upload files directly to `public/uploads` instead of `storage/app/uploads`?

I tried to set the path in `AppServiceProvider.php` but it doesn't work.

```
public function register()
{
    //not working:
    $this->app->useStoragePath( $this->app->basePath() .  "/upload");

    //also not working:
    // $this->app->bind('path.storage', function () {
    // return $this->app->basePath() . '/upload';
    // });

}
```

by "not working" I mean that it is still uploading into the default storage directory. I cleared also the cache.

Here is the upload part (used in a controller):

```
        $request->image->storeAs("uploads", "uploaded_image.jpg");
```

Thanks for any hints. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you now have to do this in `config/filesystems.php`. You can add a new disk like so:

```
'disks' => [

    'uploads' => [
          'driver' => 'local',
          'root'   => public_path(), // previously storage_path();
    ],

]
```

and then do the following to use it:

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

Comment: thank you! :) it works. In my example I was uploading an image from a form. I can also do the following to use my "uploads" disk:  $request->image->storeAs($upload_dir, "uploaded_image.jpg", "uploads");

Comment: @George H, It seems you master laravel. I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047583/how-to-add-dynamic-dropdown-list-column-on-laravel-5-3-registration

Comment: How can I access the file from Storage::url ?