# Wrong path in intervention image laravel

Tags: laravel

Following a tutorial I did this:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $file = Input::file('imagen1');
        $image = \Image::make(\Input::file('imagen1'));
        $path = public_path().'/thumbnails/';

        $image->save($path.$file->getClientOriginalName());
        $image->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $image->save($path.'thumb_'.$file->getClientOriginalName());

        $thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
        $thumbnail->image = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $thumbnail->save();

        $request->user()->propiedades()->create($request->all());
        return redirect('profile#propiedades');
    }
```

And my problem is that the image is being save in a "temporal" path and not the real one. So when i go to my table 'Propiedades' It just shows this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The right direction is this one

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

So my question is how do i make intervention image saves the real path? Thanks in advance

UPDATE

Ok. Now thanks to  Nazmul Hasan i am seeing this in my database.
The only thing left is that it saves the name of the file. So i can go to my blade and do {{ $propiedades->imagen1 }}
Thanks!!

[image]

UPDATE 2

```
$file = Input::file('imagen1');
        $ext = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('thumbnails/' . $ext);
        $image = \Image::make(\Input::file('imagen1'));


        $image->save($path.$file->getClientOriginalName());
        $image->resize(400, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $image->save($path.'thumb_'.$file->getClientOriginalName());

        $thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
        $thumbnail->image = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $thumbnail->save();

        $inputs = $request->all();
        $inputs['imagen1'] = $path;
        $request->user()->propiedades()->create($inputs);

        return redirect('profile#propiedades');
```

AND NOW IT SAVES RIGHT THE IMG PATH BUT THE IMAGE IS NOT BEING SAVE CORRECLTY

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ive answered a similar question before, and I think the answer could be the solution for you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39154586/4660602

Comment: i don't think is the same because it is saving the image withouth any problem... the problem here is that i got save the wrong path

Comment: Intervention image don't save path it only upload your image. After uploading image you must be save image path in your database

Comment: look my new update

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line

```
 $request->user()->propiedades()->create($request->all());
```

You does not update image upload path in **$request** variable
For this reason **$request->all()** save temporary image path
You can try this

```
$file = Input::file('imagen1');
$image = \Image::make(\Input::file('imagen1'));
$path = public_path().'/thumbnails/';

$image->save($path.$file->getClientOriginalName());
$image->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$image->save($path.'thumb_'.$file->getClientOriginalName());

$thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
$thumbnail->image = $path.'thumb_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$thumbnail->save();

$inputs = $request->all()
$inputs['imagen1'] = $path.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$request->user()->propiedades()->create($inputs);

return redirect('profile#propiedades');
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'your_path_index_as_database'? my sql path?

Comment: table attribute/column name for storing image path

Comment: Is a string type.