# laravel 5.8 how and where change setting that I could upload files in any place on disk

Tags: php, upload, laravel-5.8

I wanna upload files on server via my application in laravel. I do not want to save them in laravel project folder (some app\public) but in another place for example: C:\my_files. How do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change storage path in laravel 5.3 to public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154484/how-to-change-storage-path-in-laravel-5-3-to-public)

Comment: another version of laravel, the man asking in your question still wants to save files in the project folder - I wanna do this outside

Comment: the implementation is the same since its the same major version of Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances -- if the answer above is not the solution for you, I guarantee the answer is on SO.